# How to apply cdnjs css or external css to nodemailer html template using jade & express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, express

I'm trying to send mail using node mailer. Getting html mark up from jade template through external file.External file html is compiled using file stream and rendering properly whereas the style whichever inserted through **maxcdn or cdnjs** are not reflecting

in this case how to apply css or is there any other alternate way to achieve this scenario.

**Jade Template**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Application confirmation
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  body
    .container
      .row
        .col-md-4
          p Thank you for registering with us you applucation submitted succesfully
      .row
        .col-md-4
          p Thanks,
          p SnapCode Team
```

**Node Server Code**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var config_urls = require("../configfile");
var fs = require('fs');
var jade = require('jade');


function readFile() {
    var template = process.cwd() + '/public/mailTemplate/confirmation.jade';
    console.log('template', template);
    fs.readFile(template, 'utf-8', function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Template file not found!', template);
        } else {
            var compiledTmpl = jade.compile(file, { filename: template });
            htmlToSend = compiledTmpl(context);
            return htmlToSend;
        }
    });
}


module.exports = {

    SendMail: function(email, app_id, callback) {
        var template = process.cwd() + '/public/mailTemplate/confirmation.jade';
        fs.readFile(template, 'utf-8', function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Template file not found!', template);
            } else {
                var compiledTmpl = jade.compile(file, { filename: template });
                htmlToSend = compiledTmpl(context);

                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: config_urls.url.host,
                    port: config_urls.url.port,
                    secure: true, 
                    auth: {
                        user: config_urls.url.gmailID,
                        pass: config_urls.url.gmailPassword
                    }
                });

                var mailOptions = {
                    from: config_urls.url.gmailID, 
                    to: email, 
                    subject: 'Application Confirmation', 
                    html: htmlToSend
                };

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        return callback(Result = "false");
                    }
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                    return callback(Result = "true");
                });
            }
        });
    },
}; //end of function
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, be it PHP Mailing functions or node mailing functions(I have tried on both and worked with both), we cannot add external css. All we could do is write inline styles wherever it's necessary or write styles like

```
<style>
 //styles here
</style>
```

I hope that helps. Please do keep me updated. Thank you.

Comment: @krishna-m if it is a custom css we can do that think about bootstrap or foundation css will u copy and paste entire css in style tag??

Comment: @rselvaganesh That would add too much weight to the email. I'd prefer using them minimally. However am pretty much sure you cannot link to external CSS.